# How do you concatenate several 2D arrays in numpy?

Tags: numpy, insert, append, concatenation

I would like

```
np.concatenate((np.array([[5,5],[2,3]]),np.array([[6,4],[7,8]])))
```

to yield

```
[ [[5,5],[2,3]], [[6,4],[7,8]] ]
```

Concatenate doesn't do the trick, but I am lost on how else to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `numpy.stack()` or `numpy.append()` (I suggest `append` if you have a large code). just pay attention it is the `append` of numpy. not built-in `append` of python.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[5,5],[2,3]])
>>> b = np.array([[6,4],[7,8]])
>>> np.append([a], [b], axis = 0)
# answer: 
array([[[5, 5],
        [2, 3]],

       [[6, 4],
        [7, 8]]])
```

now if we go with `np.stack()`:

```
>>> d = np.stack((a,b))
>>> c == d
# answer:
array([[[ True,  True],
        [ True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True],
        [ True,  True]]])
```

as you can see they are the same.
you can see the [user guide of `numpy.append` here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html?highlight=append#numpy-append) and [user guide of `numpy.vstack` here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).

Answer (score 0):

for anyone wondering `np.stack((a,b))` does the trick :)